# Why is this Metal code not producing the correct triangle geometry?

Tags: swift, metal, mtlbuffer

I am following a Metal tutorial by Metal By Example and converting the code to Swift.

I am running the second example, and for some reason, this code is not working.

```
import UIKit
import Metal
import MetalKit
import simd

class MBEMetalView: UIView {

     // // // // // MAIN // // // // //
     var metalDevice: MTLDevice! = nil
     var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer! = nil
     var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue! = nil
     var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer! = nil
     var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState! = nil
     var displayLink: CADisplayLink! = nil

     override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
          return CAMetalLayer.self
     }
//     override func didMoveToWindow() {
//          self.redraw()
//     }
     override func didMoveToSuperview() {
          super.didMoveToSuperview()
          if self.superview != nil {
               self.displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(displayLinkFired))
               self.displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.main, forMode: .common)
          } else {
               self.displayLink.invalidate()
          }
     }
     @objc func displayLinkFired() {
          self.redraw()
     }





     // // // // // INIT // // // // //
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
          self.prepareDeviceLayerAndQueue()
          self.makeBuffers()
          self.makePipeline()
     }

     func prepareDeviceLayerAndQueue() {
          metalLayer = (self.layer as! CAMetalLayer)
          metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
          metalLayer.device = metalDevice
          metalLayer.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
          commandQueue = metalDevice.makeCommandQueue()
     }

     func makeBuffers() {
          var vertices: [MBEVertex] = [
               MBEVertex(position: vector_float4(0, 0.5, 0, 1) , color: vector_float4(1, 0, 0, 1)),
               MBEVertex(position: vector_float4(-0.5, -0.5, 0, 1)  , color: vector_float4(0, 1, 0, 1)),
               MBEVertex(position: vector_float4(0.5, -0.5, 0, 1)  , color: vector_float4(0, 0, 1, 1))
          ]
          self.vertexBuffer = metalDevice.makeBuffer(bytes: &vertices, length: 56, options: .storageModeShared)
     }

     func makePipeline() {
          guard let library = metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary() else { print("COULD NOT CREATE LIBRARY") ; return }
          guard let vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "vertex_main") else { print("COULD NOT CREATE A VERTEX FUNCTION") ; return }
          guard let fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "fragment_main") else { print("COULD NOT CREATE LIBRARY") ; return }

          let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
          pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
          pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
          pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = metalLayer.pixelFormat

          pipelineState = try? metalDevice.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
          if pipelineState == nil { print("COULD NOT CREATE PIPELINE STATE") ; return }

     }





     // // // // // FUNCTIONS // // // // //
     func redraw() {
          guard let drawable = metalLayer.nextDrawable() else { print("COULD NOT CREATE A DRAWABLE") ; return }
          let texture = drawable.texture
          let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
          renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = texture
          renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
          renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
          renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1)

          guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { print("COULD NOT CREATE A COMMAND BUFFER") ; return }
          guard let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) else { print("COULD NOT CREATE AN ENCODER") ; return }

          commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
          commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
          commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3)

          commandEncoder.endEncoding()
          commandBuffer.present(drawable)
          commandBuffer.commit()
     }





     // // // // // TYPES // // // // //
     struct MBEVertex {
          var position: vector_float4
          var color: vector_float4
     }

}
```

I am pretty sure that the shaders are not the problem because the vertex shader simply takes in the vertex buffer and return the vertex.

The fragment shader simply takes the output and of the vertex shader and returns the color.

The view controller is default -- haven't touched it.

I changed the controller's view's class to this MBEMetalView class.

I did stumble upon an error with the line of code that creates the vertex buffer with the vertices pointer, length, and option of "storageModeShared".

Originally, I set the length = to
`MemoryLayout.size(of: vertices)`
but according to the console message, that only created a length of 8 when the buffer needed a length of 32.

I simply increased the length and the error went away...

But, the triangle is distorted and not the correct color. It looks like the first 2 vertices have the correct positions but the third vertex does not.

None of the colors are correct. Any ideas?

When I change the length of the buffer - the triangle will either change shape or disappear from the screen.

Comment: After just guessing to double (a couple times) the recommended length of the buffer that was output to the console via an error when using the ``` length: MemoryLayout.size(of: vertices) ``` the triangle was rendered correctly... The correct length seems to be 128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to guess the length of the buffer. You can compute it as the number of vertices multiplied by the number of bytes occupied by each vertex:

```
let bufferLength = MemoryLayout<MBEVertex>.stride * vertices.count
self.vertexBuffer = metalDevice.makeBuffer(bytes: &vertices, length: bufferLength, options: .storageModeShared)
```

The result is actually 96 in this case.

This is generally a better approach than hard-coded constants.

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks @warrenm! I didn't include the ```<MBVertex>```

Comment: Any chance you would know why the triangle has rough sides instead of smooth sides? @warrenm